# MRT function [1] "error code = 0"

Tags: multivariate-testing

When I make my MRT, I got two errors:

> [1] "error code =  0" and Error in indval.default(Ynode, clustering =
>   clustnode, numitr = 1000) :    All species must occur in at least one
>   plot. Does anyone have an idea of why? I checked and all my species
>   have an abundance >0...

```
MRTtest=mvpart(vegetation~ Placette+ Tourb + Transect + Largcanal + Annouvert + Elevation + Profnappe + Litiere+ Solnu+ Deblign+ Densiometre+ EpaissMO+ Vonpostvingt+ Vonpostsoixante+ Pyrovingt+ Pyrosoixante+ Sommesurfterr,tot,margin=0.08,cp=0,xv="pick",xval=10,xvmult=150,which=4,pca=F)
```

> X-Val rep : 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17 
>   18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35
>   36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53
>   54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71
>   72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89
>   90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100  101  102  103  104  105 
>   106  107  108  109  110  111  112  113  114  115  116  117  118  119 
>   120  121  122  123  124  125  126  127  128  129  130  131  132  133 
>   134  135  136  137  138  139  140  141  142  143  144  145  146  147 
>   148  149  150

Minimum tree sizes
tabmins
  2   3   4   6 
  2 125   5  18

> MRTtest1=MRT(MRTtest,percent=10,species=colnames(vegetation))
>   summary(MRTtest1)
>   Portion (%) of deviance explained by species for every particular node

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    --- Node 1 ---
 Complexity(R2) 14.87422 
 Sommesurfterr>=6.024 Sommesurfterr< 6.024

~ Discriminant species : 
                       THOnmtot      THOmtot
% of expl. deviance 17.61057298 38.419650816
Mean on the left     0.37621604  0.430818462
Mean on the right    0.08877576  0.006259911
**[1] "error code =  0"**

~ INDVAL species for this node: : left is 1, right is 2
         cluster indicator_value probability
THOmtot        1          0.9597       0.001
THOnmtot       1          0.7878       0.001
LEG            1          0.5802       0.031
LIB            1          0.5078       0.010
MELnmtot       1          0.4710       0.047
EPNnmtot       1          0.4404       0.026

Sum of probabilities                 =  87.497

Sum of Indicator Values              =  30.02

Sum of Significant Indicator Values  =  12.67

Number of Significant Indicators     =  29

Significant Indicator Distribution

1  2 
 8 21

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    --- Node 2 ---
     Complexity(R2) 7.920283 
     Densiometre< 19.88 Densiometre>=19.88

```
~ Discriminant species : 
                            TRA    THOmtot
% of expl. deviance 10.54536819 27.8848051
Mean on the left     0.02754503  0.5158733
Mean on the right    0.20823621  0.2220475
```

> Error in indval.default(Ynode, clustering = clustnode, numitr = 1000)
>   :    All species must occur in at least one plot